# AttributeError after running pipenv commands

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

There is an error occured during running pipenv command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Python37\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 717, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 390, in shell
pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror,

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2156, in do_shell
three=three, python=python, validate=False, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 574, in ensure_project
pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 494, in ensure_virtualenv
python = ensure_python(three=three, python=python)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 397, in ensure_python
path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 360, in find_a_system_python
python_entry = finder.find_python_version(line)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 108, in find_python_version
match = self.windows_finder.find_python_version(

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 63, in windows_finder
self._windows_finder = WindowsFinder()

File "<attrs generated init 4868f44fa19b631f0a86b928e7558f26948d224e>", line 13, in __init__
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 92, in get_versions
py_version = PythonVersion.from_windows_launcher(version_object)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 417, in from_windows_launcher
creation_dict = cls.parse(launcher_entry.info.version)

File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\_vendor\pep514tools\_registry.py", line 75, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: version
```

Pipenv version: 2018.11.26
Python version: 3.7.2

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please include the commands that are causing this error?

Comment: It's good to check the project site for the tool too.  Looks like it's a [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3422) and scheduled to be included in the March release.  Until then, you might just want to backpedal to a previous version.

Comment: This promblem occured after running some pipenv commands (`pipenv shell`, `pipenv install`, `pipenv --python 3.7.2` etc.). I saw something similar among pipenv github issues, but it didn't help me.